# Visiting girlfriend with a B1/B2 visa regularly

Tags: usa, b1-b2-visas

I am a Turkish citizen holding a US B1/B2 visa living in Canada. My girlfriend is a Canadian citizen, holding a TN-1 visa, will be living in US in a few months. We will be visiting each other with frequent intervals (2 day visits one a month to both directions with a few potential outliers). I heard that frequent visit to partners can be considered as "intent the immigrate" by border people. How likely is it for this to cause me problems since my partner is residing in US under a non immigrant visa? Is frequent visits with full disclosed intent likely to cause problems?

Will she have problems with US border when returning to US if she leaves frequently under a TN visa?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As you tell it, your visits are frequent **but short**. That's a distinctly different pattern than trying to *live in the US* under the guise of tourist visits -- and any halfway awake border guard ought to be able to see that difference.

The usual stories of people getting into trouble concern people who're visiting their SO for weeks or months at a time and then trying to do it again after having been home for a time that barely compares to what they're spending abroad.

For peace of mind, you may want to travel with a fresh printout of your [I-94 travel history](https://i94.cbp.dhs.gov/), boarding passes from recent trips, etc., such that you can show concretely that you're actually spending much more time outside the US than inside.

Oh, and definitely disclose your intent. Lying to immigration authorities is never a good idea -- so much more when the *truth* is a perfectly legitimate story that checks out with your travel history.

Comment: I had no idea I 94 was a thing.(subject to freedom of info act at that)

Comment: It's probably worth noting that border officers have access to the I-94 history, and probably more of it, since travelers can only see the last five years' worth.  The main advantage of having a printout, it seems to me, would be the ability to physically point to dates on the paper while explaining one's travel history.  I suspect that the number of people who would benefit from this advantage would be minuscule, because most would never get to the point of needing to do so ([like OganM](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/126694/19400)).

Comment: @phoog: Indeed; I mentioned it more as a peace-of-mind thing -- something that can let one _feel_ better prepared.

Answer (score 5):

Someone asked in a deleted answer, how my experience was in practice so posting this as an alternate answer.

Henning Makholm's answer was basically correct. The border people were never adversarial so I never even bothered to bring the I-94 copy. Looking at it now, I have 24 entries into the US since June 2016 and never spent more than 5 minutes with the border people.

Note that this is from Vancouver airport so the border folks I dealt with were the ones stationed in Vancouver. Not sure how the culture differs between different points of entry, so no harm in going in prepared.